# Cannot get to compile error: 'DoublyLinkedList' does not name a type

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I have been getting the same errors for hours, making it impossible to check for algorithmic problems, i get the same errors every single time.
Errors on codeblocks:

```
C:\cygwin\home\Ryan\P1311\Playlist.h:19:4: error: 'DoublyLinkedList' does not name a type
C:\cygwin\home\Ryan\P1311\Playlist.h:22:27: error: 'string' has not been declared
C:\cygwin\home\Ryan\P1311\Playlist.h:23:29: error: 'string' has not been declared
C:\cygwin\home\Ryan\P1311\Playlist.h:24:28: error: 'string' has not been declared
C:\cygwin\home\Ryan\P1311\Playlist.h:25:27: error: 'string' has not been declared
C:\cygwin\home\Ryan\P1311\Playlist.h:27:25: error: 'string' has not been declared
```

Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)

Note: i am not allowed to change anything in the playlist.h and playlist.cpp files, they were given to me for the assignment.

```
#ifndef CSCI_311_PLAYLIST_H
#define CSCI_311_PLAYLIST_H

class Playlist {
public:
   void mainLoop();                    // process commands until done
private:
   DoublyLinkedList dll;               // playlist stored in doubly linked list

   void processCommand();              // read and process one playlist command
   void processAppendSong(string&);    // appends song to playlist
   void processInsertBefore(string&);  // insert song before current position
   void processInsertAfter(string&);   // insert song after current position
   void processRemoveSong(string&);    // removes the specified song
   void processPlayCurrent();          // "plays" song at the current position
   void processGotoSong(string&);      // sets the current position to song
   void processGotoFirstSong();        // goes to the first song
   void processGotoLastSong();         // goes to the last song
   void processNextSong();             // go to next song
   void processPrevSong();             // go to previous song
   void processPlayForward();          // "play" all songs from current to end
   void processPlayReverse();          // "play" all songs from current to start
};

#endif // CSCI_311_PLAYLIST_H
```

Comment: Headers shouldn't depend on other headers being included first. Point that out.

Comment: you need to include header file where DoublyLinkedList is defined. and #include <string>...

Comment: You been given some real rubbish. The best person to ask is the teacher who gave you those files. And if this is the best that teacher can do then another course might be a good idea.